# WPF populate treeview selection into a textbox

Tags: wpf, textbox, treeview

Any help is appreciated. I'm very new to WPF.  I have a treeview that is being populated by an xml file.  When the treeview item is selected, I need it to show up in a text box.  I have the treeview inside a popup and I've got it so that when the textbox in question is selected, it will bring up the popup with treeview prompting the user to make a selection on the treeview.  Afterwards it should put that treeview selection back into the same textbox.  Here's my code:

```
    <TextBox Name="text"
    Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.name, ElementName=dirTree}"
    Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxStyle}"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="47,326,110,140"
    TextChanged="text_TextChanged" />
```

And the treeview portion:

```
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=text}"
                       VerticalOffset="20"
                       HorizontalOffset="-180"
                       Margin="0,0,465,279"
                       Name="popup1"
                       AllowsTransparency="True"
                       Placement="Top">
                    <Popup.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=text, Path=IsFocused}"
                                             Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsOpen"
                                            Value="True" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=popupText, Path=IsFocused}"
                                             Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsOpen"
                                            Value="True" />
                                </DataTrigger>-->
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Popup.Style>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2"
                                Background="DodgerBlue"
                                BorderBrush="DodgerBlue"
                                Padding="0"
                                CornerRadius="6">

                            <ScrollViewer Height="300"
                                          Name="scrollViewer1"
                                          Width="175"
                                          BorderBrush="Black"
                                          Background="DodgerBlue">
                                <TreeView Name="dirTree"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmldata}, XPath=.}"
                                          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
                                          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                                          GotFocus="TreeView1_GotFocus"
                                          SelectedItemChanged="{Binding ElementName=dirTree, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>

                </Popup>
```

Comment: what are you doing here `SelectedItemChanged="{Binding ElementName=dirTree, Path=SelectedItem}"/>` how does that even compile??, You seem to be trying to bind an `Eventhandler`(SelectedItemChanged) to its own `SelectedItem` (object) ???

Comment: The trigger for the popup box is the on same textbox that I want the treeview selection populated back into. That's what I'm **trying** to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an event handler on the SelectedItemChanged event from your TreeView and from there, update your TextBlock.Text.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TreeView x:Name="demoTreeView"
              Margin="10"
              SelectedItemChanged="demoTreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
    </TreeView>

    <TextBlock x:Name="demoTextBox" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

And in the .cs file :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        demoTreeView.Items.Add("test1");
        demoTreeView.Items.Add("test2");
        demoTreeView.Items.Add("test3");
        demoTreeView.Items.Add("test4");
    }

    private void demoTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        demoTextBox.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
    }

}
```

Personalty I would recommend you to use MVVM and bindings on Properties in order to have a nice decoupling between the xaml and the code-behind.

Comment: Thank you.  This helps some.  It returns "System.Xml.XmlElement" into the text box instead of the selection (which should be something like "Zone A") but at least it's now returning something.

Comment: try to cast the e.NewValue to an XmlElement and extract the value out of it.